# Is 'all of which accompanies the meaning and goes beyond it' grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, subject-verb-agreement, relative-pronouns

In this passage from ["Understanding the Subject of a Poem"](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/poetry/understanding-the-subject-of-a-poem/):

> Instead, people go to the trouble [of writing poetry] because poems sound a certain way, are built in certain shapes, and have certain beauties in sound and meaning—**all of which accompanies the meaning and goes beyond it**.

... is "all of which accompanies the meaning and goes beyond it" grammatically correct?

Comment: Welcome! I took the liberty of editing your question to link to the source and format the quote. However, could you please edit as well to say what it is you think might be wrong about it? I suspect that you're wondering why "accompanies" is a singular verb, when "all of which" refers to a series of points. If so (or if not), please clarify.

Comment: Yes, perfectly grammatically correct. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: To paraphrase 'all of which' in the sentence above, it can be ' and all of them.' isn't it? I mean " ~~~~ and all of them accompany the meaning and go beyond it." is correct, isn't it? And what does the last word 'it' indicate in this sentence? Could you be more specific if I am mistaken?

Comment: Do you mean that if you mean "all of which is all of it," 'all of a singular noun' like 'all of one' is grammatically possible? I am not contradicting, but I am just asking.

Answer (score -1):

**Why is *accompanies* singular?** It's a good point. What comes before the quoted portion is a series. If I used a simpler sentence,

> "I have a baseball, a basketball, and a tennis ball, all of which **are** round"

—then I would use the plural verb "are," because there are three things acting as the subject to that verb. So yes, you could argue that "accompanies" is a grammatical error and the writer should have used "accompany."

But it's not necessarily so simple. The series is made up not of simple nouns, but of more complex phrases. "Poems sound... , are built... , and have... ." It's a little hard to treat these phrases as a compound subject and apply them all to yet another verb. Instead, you could take "all of which" as combining all those sentiments into one (singular) whole. Imagine this sentence:

> Dogs defend their owners, come when called, and are always eager to play, all of which shows that they are not cats.

Here I again chose the singular verb *shows*, "bundling up" all these observations about dogs into a unit.

Is this grammatically defensible? I'm not sure, but it's hard to make too strong a case *against* it.

**What does the last word, *it*, mean?**

This is just a pronoun, standing in for the most recent noun, *meaning*. The author is saying that a poem's sound, shape, and beauty "accompany"—go "along with"—the poem's meaning, and also "go *beyond*" the poem's meaning. In other words, saying something in a poetic way does more than just communicate meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation, which is very convincing. And can you tell me what the last word "it" indicates in the sentence?

Comment: *All* does not bundle anything.  All functions like a plural pronoun, similar to *they*.  Do you say *They is coming to visit?*  It means *all* of them.

Comment: @EllieK "I have indigestion, there's a dog barking outside, and my pillow is lumpy. All this makes it hard for me to sleep." Was I wrong to choose singular for "this" and "makes"? I'm not sure I'm convinced that it's *right*, but it's clearly common, and the best that I can explain it is as above.

Comment: *All **this** makes it hard for me to sleep but **all** make it hard for me to sleep.*

Comment: @EllieK True. So, my thought was that "all of which" functions semantically the same as "all of this." As I say, I have my own doubts, but it's the best explanation I can come up with.